aws apigateway / curl: supplied header is not detected
I'm getting this message:
$ curl --request POST --header 'Content-MD5: a6474a1b1a0795c4891ba2962543361f' 'https://bad1udgbzk.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443/des/document'
{
  "message": "Missing required request parameters: [Content-MD5]"
}

As you can see, I'm setting Content-MD5 header.
Here my resource method details:
$ aws apigateway get-method --rest-api-id "bad1udgbzk" --resource-id "5vh219" --http-method "POST"
{
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "authorizationType": "NONE",
  "apiKeyRequired": false,
  "requestValidatorId": "487mvx",
  "requestParameters": {
    "method.request.header.Content-MD5": true
  },
  "methodIntegration": {
    "type": "AWS_PROXY",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:058264555121:function:frontoffice-lambda-des-pushDocument/invocations",
    "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
    "timeoutInMillis": 29000,
    "cacheNamespace": "5vh219",
    "cacheKeyParameters": []
  }
}

As you can see, "requestParameters": {"method.request.header.Content-MD5": true} is set.
I don't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I've also tried to invoke method using aws cli:
$ aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id "bad1udgbzk" --resource-id "5vh219" --http-method "POST" --headers "Content-MD5= sdfsfd"

{
  "status": 200,
  "body": "{\"id\":\"8ea6fab3-d553-4936-be9a-27979b30543d\",\"pushUrl\":\"https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/espaidoc-des/8ea6fab3-d553-4936-be9a-27979b30543d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240403T140326Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQ3EGWRZYSIU7ENEO%2F20240403%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=49a5bfeba0c2fd48b135aa7edac66a30c359099f013f5c13357ec75175ba5fa9\"}",
  "headers": {
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-660d61ae-8295f7c6742396121f9333c5;Parent=74cf6ef1ee782bb3;Sampled=0;lineage=1042b66c:0"
  },
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
      "Root=1-660d61ae-8295f7c6742396121f9333c5;Parent=74cf6ef1ee782bb3;Sampled=0;lineage=1042b66c:0"
    ]
  },
  "log": "Execution log for request b2ba1df3-3264-4852-9f90-ea7e44f41717\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Starting execution for request: b2ba1df3-3264-4852-9f90-ea7e44f41717\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /document\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Method request path: {}\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Method request query string: {}\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Method request headers: {Content-MD5=sdfsfd}\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Method request body before transformations: \nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Request validation succeeded for content type application/json\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:058264555121:function:frontoffice-lambda-des-pushDocument/invocations\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Endpoint request headers: {X-Amz-Date=20240403T140326Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=bad1udgbzk, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_bad1udgbzk, Host=lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, X-Amz-Content-Sha256=c99814a1fd7b16b4f05d5c5709580776e69416924b32434788c62628a03b5c30, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-660d61ae-8295f7c6742396121f9333c5, x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=b2ba1df3-3264-4852-9f90-ea7e44f41717, Authorization=*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************31785f, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:058264555121:bad1udgbzk/test-invoke-stage/POST/document, X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEE4aCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDTV6tYXsyM+KI4nkM0iipKnf7H4XMMoF7B8osu2SzsYgIhANvSnkMa7dSthaA44vUU9a6xS8+zTdR0Yqoe0tvXMIyfKrEF [TRUNCATED]\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {\"resource\":\"/document\",\"path\":\"/document\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\",\"headers\":{\"Content-MD5\":\"sdfsfd\"},\"multiValueHeaders\":{\"Content-MD5\":[\"sdfsfd\"]},\"queryStringParameters\":null,\"multiValueQueryStringParameters\":null,\"pathParameters\":null,\"stageVariables\":null,\"requestContext\":{\"resourceId\":\"5vh219\",\"resourcePath\":\"/document\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\",\"extendedRequestId\":\"VpwzPGZQjoEFdeA=\",\"requestTime\":\"03/Apr/2024:14:03:26 +0000\",\"path\":\"/document\",\"accountId\":\"058264555121\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"stage\":\"test-invoke-stage\",\"domainPrefix\":\"testPrefix\",\"requestTimeEpoch\":1712153006098,\"requestId\":\"b2ba1df3-3264-4852-9f90-ea7e44f41717\",\"identity\":{\"cognitoIdentityPoolId\":null,\"cognitoIdentityId\":null,\"apiKey\":\"test-invoke-api-key\",\"principalOrgId\":null,\"cognitoAuthenticationType\":null,\"userArn\":\"arn:aws:iam::058264555121:user/jordi.cabre\",\"apiKeyId\":\"test-invoke-api-key-id\",\"userAgent\":\"aws-cli/2.15.30 Python/3.11.8 Linux/6.8.1-arch1-1 exe/x86_64.archcraft prompt/off command [TRUNCATED]\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Sending request to https://lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:058264555121:function:frontoffice-lambda-des-pushDocument/invocations\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 87 ms\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Wed, 03 Apr 2024 14:03:26 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=507, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=bc562f55-78d2-4a47-8265-134398bfe40e, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-660d61ae-8295f7c6742396121f9333c5;parent=74cf6ef1ee782bb3;sampled=0;lineage=1042b66c:0}\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {\"statusCode\":200,\"headers\":null,\"multiValueHeaders\":null,\"body\":\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"8ea6fab3-d553-4936-be9a-27979b30543d\\\",\\\"pushUrl\\\":\\\"https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/espaidoc-des/8ea6fab3-d553-4936-be9a-27979b30543d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240403T140326Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQ3EGWRZYSIU7ENEO%2F20240403%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=49a5bfeba0c2fd48b135aa7edac66a30c359099f013f5c13357ec75175ba5fa9\\\"}\",\"isBase64Encoded\":null}\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Method response body after transformations: {\"id\":\"8ea6fab3-d553-4936-be9a-27979b30543d\",\"pushUrl\":\"https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/espaidoc-des/8ea6fab3-d553-4936-be9a-27979b30543d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240403T140326Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQ3EGWRZYSIU7ENEO%2F20240403%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=49a5bfeba0c2fd48b135aa7edac66a30c359099f013f5c13357ec75175ba5fa9\"}\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-660d61ae-8295f7c6742396121f9333c5;Parent=74cf6ef1ee782bb3;Sampled=0;lineage=1042b66c:0}\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Successfully completed execution\nWed Apr 03 14:03:26 UTC 2024 : Method completed with status: 200\n",
  "latency": 91
}

As you can see, it works.
I've also tried to change method configuration to receivce contentmd5 header instead of Content-MD5 and it has worked.
Any ideas about how to debug or get any additional information about this issue?
